# Can't figure out why PUT request won't update data

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, httprequest, httpresponse

So I'm running a node.js server with express that has this data. Ultimately I am trying to submit close notes, from a form in my html page, to update the close notes in this data set, which is hard coded into the node server for now.

```
var data = [
{
    inc_num: "INC0001",
    close_notes: "blah"
},
{
    inc_num: "INC0002",
    close_notes: ""
},
]
```

these are the three back end http requests.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});


app.put('/update/:inc_num', (req, res) => {
    delete data.close_notes;
    var body = req.body
    data.close_notes = body.close_notes;
    res.status(200).send('ACK');
});

app.get('/update', (req, res) => {   
    res.send(data);
});
```

Here is the AJAX request from the front end

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/update/' + inc_num,
    type: 'PUT',
    constentType: "application/json",
    data: dataPut,
    success: function(){
        console.log('PUT SUCCESS');
    }

 })
```

The way it is right now nothing changes at all.

I know for a fact that the front end is sending the correct data through because if I change the function in the app.put to data.push(req.body) it adds the correct information I passed into the data array. I am either not understanding something about PUT request correctly or am just messing something up in the function of the back end PUT request.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `constentType: "application/json",`  <= what is a "constent" type? ^_^

Comment: whoops typo, changed it to contentType, but after I fixed the typo the console is giving me 400 bad request. Edit: if I remove "contentType" all together it goes back to normal.

Comment: "normal" being...?

Comment: returning original data, close_notes remains the same

Comment: `data` is an array and arrays don't have properties like `close_notes`. You need to look inside the array. Also need to store that data somewhere other than hard code

Comment: @charlietfl do you know how I could go about selecting the object property inside the array? Also, I will be switching to a database once I get this PUT resolved.

Comment: Use `Array.prototype.find()`

Comment: Ah ha! awesome I'm grabbing just the one object I want now! Thank you so much, now just to write the replacement code for the close_notes.